# Labels & SpeedButtons not showing in Glass Frame - Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, aero, delphi-xe4, aero-glass

Look at the picture below. when I add a label and a Speed Button and run the program, none of them will show but the label that has a glow ( `GlowSize=1` )

[image: Picture 1]

When I run the program:

[image: Picture2]

You see? Even the second label is not showing correctly and it's very transparent.

Is there any workarounds to fix this problem? Thanks :)

- Delphi XE4

Comment: Set the form DoubleBuffered property to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set DoubleBuffered property of the form TRUE.
After that TLable/TSpeedButton should be shown.
But those Glass* related features are buggy and bad documented anyway.